# sending multiple values from input field in form not working in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have an html form in which a field is multiple selection boxes like below:

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                    <select multiple name="Fee[]">
                                        <option value="6000">Event Manager Rs 6,000</option>
                                        <option value="5000">Vendor Rs 5,000</option>
                                        <option value="4000">Artist Rs 4,000</option>
                                        <option value="3000">Manpower Supply Rs 3,000</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

below is the php code for the value to get selected and go into email:

```html
  $fee = $request->Fee[0];
              $data->Fee = $fee;

              if(!empty($request->Fee[1]))
              {
               $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[1];
              }

                            if(!empty($request->Fee[2]))
                            {
                             $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[2];
                            }

                                          if(!empty($request->Fee[3]))
                                          {
                                           $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[3];
                                          }
```

with this code only first 2 values is passed to the email, can anyone tell whats wrong in my code

Comment: You're setting both `Fee[2]` and `Fee[3]` to `$data->Fee1` so they will just overwrite what was in `$data->Fee1`

Comment: @MER how should i do it then, can you write as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You are setting multiple values to `$data->Fee1`. I imagine you want something like this:

```php
$fee = $request->Fee[0];
$data->Fee = $fee;

if (!empty($request->Fee[1])) {
    $data->Fee1 = $request->Fee[1];
}

if (!empty($request->Fee[2])) {
    $data->Fee2 = $request->Fee[2];
}

if (!empty($request->Fee[3])) {
    $data->Fee3 = $request->Fee[3];
}
```

Comment: let me check    ,,,,,,,,